# How can I hook structure members in frida

Tags: reverse-engineering, frida

I have a code like this:

```
class CURLNetRequest : public CNetRequestBase
{
    DEFINE_LOGCLASS;
    
    struct ProxySettings
    {
        void initFromConfig();
        
        String  host;
        int     port;
        String  username;
        String  password;
    };

    struct AuthSettings
    {
        AuthSettings( AuthMethod m, const String& u, const String& p )
        : method(m)
        , user(u)
        , password(p)
        {}

        const AuthMethod method;
        const String user;
        const String password;
    };
...
```

I want to hook the `structure` members i.e. `user` and `password` using `frida`. so far I did like below:

```
const some_func_pointer = Module.getExportByName('librhodes.so', '_ZN3rho3net14CURLNetRequest10CURLHolder11set_optionsEPKcRKNSt6__ndk
112basic_stringIcNS5_11char_traitsIcEENS5_9allocatorIcEEEESD_PNS0_11IRhoSessionEPNS_9HashtableISB_SB_EERKNS1_13ProxySettingsERKNS1_12AuthSettingsE');
const some_func = new NativeFunction(some_func_pointer, "void", ["int", "pointer"]);
Interceptor.replace(some_func_pointer, new NativeCallback(function (size, data) {
  console.log(size)
  console.log(data.readUtf8String())
  some_func(size, data);
}, "void", ["int", "pointer"]));
```

and I can only get the `AuthMethod m` which could either be `POST` or `GET` in this case. How can I hook others like `username` and `password`.

FYI, this is [rhomobile](https://github.com/rhomobile/) built app, and the above snippet taken from the [open source code](https://github.com/rhomobile/rhodes/blob/0296271a56699e15fef45209473fb9bcd20a5639/platform/shared/net/CURLNetRequest.h), so apparently decompiling `librhodes.so`  produces some stripped functions, etc.

please help me with this.

Comment: As the code is C++ I assume the `String` type is effectively the C++ type `std::string`. If that is true then you can't read the string content using `readUtf8String()`. Instead you need to convert the String to a C string by calling `std::string::c_str`.

Comment: `console.log(data.std::string::c_str)` is this the correct syntax?

Comment: No, you can not call c++ functions from within frida directly. You first have to get the `NativePointer` of the function and then you can call it.

Comment: then How can I get `NativePointer` of the function. I am a noob here.

Comment: @Robert well, I have tried something like this: `console.log(Module.getExportByName('librhodes.so', '_ZN3rho3net14CURLNetRequest10CURLHolder11set_
optionsEPKcRKNSt6__ndk112basic_stringIcNS5_11char_traitsIcEENS5_9allocatorIcEEEESD_PNS0_11IRhoSessionEPNS_9HashtableISB
_SB_EERKNS1_13ProxySettingsERKNS1_12AuthSettingsE'))` which returns `function address`  for example `0xc4d755d4` and I used `NativePointer` as `var memAddr = new NativePointer('0xc4d755d4');` then to read it from like `memAddr.readU32();`. this output random number of integer.

Comment: Sorry my fault, not `NativePointer` but `NativeFunction` similar the way you have defined your `some_func`. I don't know which library exports `data.std::string::c_str` in your hooked environment. Some people even compile a special library they load into the hooked process for getting the function like shown [here](https://stek29.rocks/2017/08/07/frida-stdstring.html).  Alternatively you can try https://codeshare.frida.re/@oleavr/read-std-string/

Comment: @Robert, thanks for sharing this. when I modified `fridaJs` as `const some_func = new NativeFunction(some_func_pointer, "pointer", ["int", "pointer" , "pointer", "pointer", "pointer",
 "pointer", "pointer"]);
Interceptor.replace(some_func_pointer, new NativeCallback(function (size, data) {
  console.log(size)
  console.log(readStdString(data))
  //some_func(size, data);
}, "pointer", ["pointer", "pointer", "pointer", "pointer", "pointer", "pointer"]));` with `oleavr/read-std-string` now I'm getting this:

Comment: `0xd2cc6d24
OST
Error: expected a pointer
0xbecdc824
r☻
Error: expected a pointer
0xbecdc824
r☻
Error: expected a pointer`, is it only reading some parts of what I wanted? I got confused

Answer (score 1):

pass the function name to `NativeFunction` module and the exptected pointers then print in the console the data in the callback function. although this is not what you expected in your original question but leads to somewhere. make trials then though.

```
const some_func = new NativeFunction(some_func_pointer, "pointer", ["int", "pointer" , "pointer", "pointer", "pointer",  "pointer", "pointer"]); 

Interceptor.replace(some_func_pointer, new NativeCallback(function (size, data) {   console.log(size)   console.log(readStdString(data))   //some_func(size, data); }, "pointer", ["pointer", "pointer", "pointer", "pointer", "pointer", "pointer"]));
```